# What view should be use to load the static local html file?

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview, android-websettings

In my appplication i have to load the abc.html file in to specific layout.
So for that which view i have to use ?
Should i WebView is fine. or there is anyother View that load that local html file fast.

Note: the Html file is not loading from the server or internate. but it is tha local file that we stored in to assets directory.

Comment: refer the link : http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-498656.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to use WebView for rendering HTML tags, CSS and Java script

Answer (score 1):

A WebView has the ability to load HTML Files and all the functionality behind the website functionality. I recommend using this.

Answer (score 1):

use webview.

```
   WebView wv;  
   wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
   wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/aboutcertified.html"); // ur path of HTML
```